# Order-of-growth of selection sort is quadratic, it takes 2secs to sort 100 elements, what will be the expected completion time to sort 200 elements?

Tags: algorithms, runtime-analysis, sorting

The above is an *MCQ* from an online quiz given by my *Algorithm* lecturer. The available options are **6secs**, **4secs**, **12secs** and **20secs**.

The answer I selected was **12secs** and it was rejected. The lecturer said the answer should be **4secs** and then I started to prove that the answer is **greater than or equal to 8secs** in the following ways.

---

#### 1. Using *Proportions*

**T = kN<sup>2</sup>**, *where k is an arbitrary constant*

2 = k x (100<sup>2</sup>)       **-------------(1)**

x = k x (200<sup>2</sup>)       **-------------(2)**

***(2)/(1)*** implies, x/2 = 200<sup>2</sup>/100<sup>2</sup> = 2<sup>2</sup> = 4,

*i.e.* x/2 = 4 but **x** = 2 x 4 = **8secs**

---

#### 2. Using *'doubling hypothesis'*

***NOTE:*** This is almost identical to the first proof.

Running Time = aN<sup>b</sup>, *where b = 2*

2 = 100<sup>2</sup>a, and a = 2/100<sup>2</sup>

Then again, **Time** = aN<sup>2</sup> = (2/100<sup>2</sup>)N<sup>2</sup> =(2/100<sup>2</sup>) x 200<sup>2</sup> = 2 x 4 = **8secs**

---

#### 3. Using a slide from a reliable source

As you can see the ratio **T(2N)/T(N) = 4** for *Selection Sort*

Suppose the answer is **4secs**,

**T(2N)/T(N)** = 4/2 = **2** and the order-of-growth becomes *linear* and this proves the answer 4sec is wrong.

Whereas when you substitute the answer **8secs**,

**T(2N)/T(N)** = 8/2 = **4** and proves that the order-of-growth is *quadratic* according to this slide.

[image: T(2N)/T(N) ratio]

---

#### 4. By ploting the curve on a graph

[image: T(2N)-T(N) graph]

Both the points **(100,2)** and **(200,8)** satisfies *Y=mX<sup>2</sup>* and *m = 2 x 10<sup>-2</sup>*, and I proved it through equations as well to show that the curve is quadratic and not cubic or else. Also plotted the straight line for the points **(100,2)** and **(200,4)**.

---

Finally, the lecturer agrees that the answer should be **8secs** but since that option is missing I should select the closest approximation which is **6secs**.

But my point is the running time should be greater than or equal to **8secs** and at the same time closest to **8secs** because there are other basic operations involved as well like *variable declaration, initiation, comparison, swap function* and for small inputs the time taken for those aren't negligible. So the answer **12secs** is my answer in the given context.

***Although we can't tell the exact running time, what do you think is the possible range for running time? and, is my argument valid or not?***

I thank you in advance!

Comment: Your lecturer made a mistake. The intended answer should have been 8 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

First off, that's a less than wonderful question.

Second: If the running time is indeed quadratic (with no linear term), the best answer is **8 seconds**, not 4 seconds.  Suppose the running time is $T(n) = c \cdot n^2$ for some constant $c$.  Then we know $T(100) = $ 2 seconds.  One can show that

$$T(200) = c \cdot 200^2 = c \cdot 4 \cdot 100^2 = 4 \times T(100),$$

so it follows that $T(200) =$ 8 seconds.

That said, I still don't like the question very much.  Usually when we say that an algorithm has quadratic running time, we mean that its running time is in $\Theta(n^2)$.  That means the running time could be something like $T(n) = c_1 \cdot n^2 + c_2 \cdot n$.  If the running time looks like that, then we don't have enough information to conclude what the running time will be for $n=200$.

Comment: I preferred "a crummy question" :-)

Comment: If T(100) = 2 seconds for selection sort of 100 items, then _something_ very unusual is going on here. 2 seconds is an awful long time for that kind of operation, so I wouldn't dare making any predictions for T(200) until I understood where the enormous time for T(100) comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers **4secs** and  **6secs** given by the lecturer are correct since those are the only possibilities.

*My friend derived to this conclusion based on the following calculation*,

**T(N)  =    a(N<sup>2</sup>) + bN   + c  = 2**, where ***'bN+ c'*** is **not neglegible** for small input size like 200 elements.

> **T(2N) = 4a(N<sup>2</sup>) + 2bN + c   <  4a(N<sup>2</sup>) + 4bN +4c**
>
> **T(2N) < 4[a(N<sup>2</sup>) + bN  + c ]**
>
> **< 4T(N)**
>
> **< 4 x 2**
>
> **T(2N)  < 8secs**

At the same time ,

> **T(2N) > T(N)**
>
> **T(2N)  > 2secs**

This gives the range for T(2N) as below,

> ***2secs < T(2N) < 8secs***

Since both of those answers are within this range, this proves my argument is **invalid**.

Comment: There is no reason to assume that T (n) is a polynomial, no reason to assume that b and c are positive. You cannot even assume that T (200) > T (100).